# How using "dot" (or "matmul") function for iterative multiplication in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I need obtain a "W" matrix of multiples matrix multiplications (all multiplications result in column vectors).

```
from numpy import matrix
from numpy import transpose
from numpy import matmul
from numpy import dot

# Iterative matrix multiplication
def iterativeMultiplication(X, Y):
    W = [] # Matrix of matricial products
    X = matrix(X) # same number of rows
    Y = matrix(Y) # same number of rows
    h = 0
    while (h < X.shape[1]):
        W.append([])
        W[h] = dot(transpose(X), Y) # using "dot" function
        h += 1
    return W
```

But, unexpectedly, I obtain a list of objects with their respective data types.

```
X = [[0., 0., 1.], [1.,0.,0.], [2.,2.,2.], [2.,5.,4.]]
Y = [[-0.2], [1.1], [5.9], [12.3]] # Edit Y column 
iterativeMultiplication( X, Y )
```

Results in:

```
[array([[37.5],[73.3],[60.8]]), 
array([[37.5],[73.3],[60.8]]),
array([[37.5],[73.3],[60.8]])]
```

I need any method for obtain only the numerical values for the matrix conversion.

```
W = matrix(W) # Results in error
```

It is the same using "matmul" function. Thx for your time.

Comment: This isn't valid Python code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stack multiple matrices, you can use [`numpy.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html):

```
W = numpy.vstack(W)
```

Edit: There seems to be a discrepancy between your function, X and Y versus the "result" list in your question. But based on your comments below, what you're actually looking for is [`numpy.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) (horizontal stack) which will give you the desired 3x3 matrix based on your "result" list.

```
W = numpy.hstack(W)
```

Comment: I need to get "h" columns. In this case h = 3. using "vstack" I get a matrix of 9x1. The correct thing would be a 3x3 matrix. Thx for your response =)

Comment: how do you expect a 3x3 matrix if W is a list of three 3x2 matrices?

Comment: I suggest you add an example of your desired output in your question.

Comment: Check my updated answer, your result in the question doesn't match the actual output of your function with the given input X and Y (hence the misunderstanding).

Comment: Yep, I need one column (product) for each multiplication. In this case the "hstack" function it works perfectly. I obtain a matrix of 3x3. Thx for you response!

Comment: I watched his response. My code is very large. Sorry for the delay :( ... I did not want a "-1" :( ...

Comment: Sorry for my error. The correct Y column is: Y = [[-0.2], [1.1], [5.9], [12.3]] ... Thx for your response!

Comment: `hstack` is just `concatenate(..., axis=-1)` - i.e. concatenate on the last axis.  Since the inputs are 2d (column vectors), this does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you are going to get a list.  You initial `W` as a list, and append the same calculation to it 3 times.

But your 3 element arrays don't make sense with this data, `array([[ 3.36877336],[ 3.97112615],[ 3.8092797 ]])`.

If I make `Xm=np.matrix(X)`, etc:

```
In [162]: Xm
Out[162]: 
matrix([[ 0.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.],
        [ 2.,  5.,  4.]])
In [163]: Ym
Out[163]: 
matrix([[  0.1,  -0.2],
        [  0.9,   1.1],
        [  6.2,   5.9],
        [ 11.9,  12.3]])
In [164]: Xm.T.dot(Ym)
Out[164]: 
matrix([[ 37.1,  37.5],
        [ 71.9,  73.3],
        [ 60.1,  60.8]])

In [165]: Xm.T*Ym   # matrix interprets * as .dot
Out[165]: 
matrix([[ 37.1,  37.5],
        [ 71.9,  73.3],
        [ 60.1,  60.8]])
```

You need to edit the question, to have both valid Python code (missing `def` and `:`), and results that match the inputs.

===============

```
In [173]:  Y = [[-0.2], [1.1], [5.9], [12.3]] 
In [174]: Ym=np.matrix(Y)
Out[176]: 
matrix([[ 37.5],
        [ 73.3],
        [ 60.8]])
```

=====================

This iteration is clumsy:

```
h = 0
while (h < X.shape[1]):
    W.append([])
    W[h] = dot(transpose(X), Y) # using "dot" function
    h += 1
```

A more Pythonic approach

```
for h in range(X.shape[1]):
    W.append(np.dot(...))
```

Or even

```
W = [np.dot(....) for h in range(X.shape[1])]
```

Comment: Sorry for my error. The correct Y column is:
    Y = [[-0.2], [1.1], [5.9], [12.3]]

Comment: Yep. In my complete code I use scaling, and preprocessing. That's why I get this way ... excuse the confusion. The idea was that he needed the matrix with that number of rows and columns. Thx for your colaboration! =)